# File name does not change when changing 'Save as type'

Tags: python, python-2.7, window, easygui

I'm on Python 2.7 using [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/api.html#easygui.filesavebox) Version: 0.97.4. When trying to use filesavebox the file name isn't updating when I change the value of 'Save as type' in the file explorer dialog.  When selecting a value I expect the filename to reflect the changes by updating the extension - 'Merged Image.gif', 'Merged Image.jpg' etc.

```
available_file_types = ["*.jpeg", "*.jpg", "*.gif",
                        "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.webp", "Images"]
easygui.filesavebox(msg="Save your new image",
                         title="Image Merger", 
                         default="Merged Image.jpg",
                         filetypes=available_file_types)
```

Comment: @martineau my apologies.  Updated question with requested details.

Comment: I have a slightly older version of `easygui` installed (0.96). In it the `filesavebox()` function is just a thin wrapper around a call to `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`, so the functionality you're getting is a result of how that function works — and changing it would require a change to the `Tkinter` module.